# ¿Cómo ejecutar un Alert mientras el dispositivo se encuentra bloqueado?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo un Service y un BroadcastReceiver para ejecutar un temporizador en segundo plano y además mostrarlo en otras activities. Cuando el temporizador se termina yo muestro una alerta mostrando que el tiempo se ha agotado y redirecciono a el usuario a el inicio de la aplicación, pero me encontré con que al tener bloqueado el celular y el tiempo sigue corriendo hasta llegar a 0, la alerta no me aparece al desbloquearlo, por lo cual no se redirecciona el usuario. ¿Cómo puedo mostrar una alerta al desbloquear el celular? Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para lograrlo necesitas definir un Receiver que se ejecute cada vez que el usuario desbloquee el dispositivo. Lo defines en el `AndroidManifest` de esta manera.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".StartAlert">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Luego debes crear la clase `StartAlert` que extienda a `BroadcastReceiver` e implementas el código para comprobar si el temporizador ha finalizado y muestras la alerta

StartAlert.java

```
public class StartAlert extends BroadcastReceiver {

    //Este método se ejecuta cada vez que el usuario desbloquea el dispositivo
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Compruebas si el temporizador ha finalizado y muestras la alerta
    }
}
```

Comment: Para la proxima @hector te recomiendo que pongas el código que tienes hasta el momento así puedes obtener respuestas mas rápido. Revisa [ask] para que entendamos mejor. Espero te sirva mi respuesta. Gracias.